# Execution time benchmarks for web automation

Tags: automation, mshtml, browser-automation, webautomation

Are there any automation execution time related industry standards/benchmarks are available for performing different actions on web page. 
Like through automation; how much time can be considered as acceptable time for setting value to text box (like 1 sec for 20characters) or what range of time will be considered as acceptable for clicking on button, selecting value from combobox, selecting checkbox available in grid etc.

Comment: Why is there a "/" in the title?  "standard/execution" is not like "and/or".  What does the "/" mean here?  Also, who's standards do you want?  ANSI?  ISO?  IEEE?  POSIX?  W3C?  OMG?

Comment: yes the "/" is for "and/or". I am looking for acceptable industry benchmarks but not looking specifically for any standards. The main intention is to know the values which will give me an idea whether function's execution time is within acceptable range or not.

Comment: "/" does not mean "and/or".  "/" is a mysterious punctuation mark sometimes used with "and/or" to indicate both (i.e., an inclusive or).  In this question, it's uninterpretable.  Please revise the question title to make it clear what -- specifically -- you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about a standard list, but there is [SpecWeb2005](http://www.spec.org/web2005/) and also [TPC-W e-commerce benchmark](http://www.tpc.org/tpcw/default.asp) (obsolete, but ppl still use it). you could compare different automated testing solutions against each other when simulating those benchmarks. Transactions per second, # of virtual users, etc.